# F-acyclic Objects that are not Flat nor Injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Does anyone know an example of an additive functor $F:A \to B$ between abelian categories that is not exact, such that its $F$-acyclic objects are not flat (hence not projective nor free) and not injective? Does it exist?

Comment: If $F$ is exact, any object is $F$-acyclic.

Comment: You are right, I have edited it.

Comment: So what exactly you are searching for? A left exact covariant functor and an object which is acyclic with respect to the right derived functors, but neither flat nor injective?